# Several crashes with a new build: 20.04 LTS over MSI b450 Ryzen 3700x

Tags: 20.04, hardware

I built my new PC with a Ryzen 3700x, an MSI b450 motherboard and a fresh 20.04 LTS.

I have some troubles: sometimes after 10 or 20 second after resume the system freezes with some activity on the hard disk led, some activity on a network led but without any response. No ping no ctrl alt f.

Sometime the kernel crashes and put my btrfs / opt / vault partition in read only. I attach dmesg content

```
[mar giu 30 22:36:21 2020] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[mar giu 30 22:36:21 2020] BTRFS: Transaction aborted (error -17)
[mar giu 30 22:36:21 2020] WARNING: CPU: 9 PID: 1396 at fs/btrfs/extent-tree.c:2188 btrfs_run_delayed_refs+0x13c/0x190 [btrfs]
[mar giu 30 22:36:21 2020] Modules linked in: uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_common videodev nls_utf8 isofs snd_seq_dummy snd_hrtimer vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) xt_CHECKSUM xt_MASQUERADE xt_conntrack ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 xt_tcpudp ip6table_mangle ip6table_nat iptable_mangle iptable_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_tables nfnetlink ip6table_filter ip6_tables iptable_filter bpfilter bridge stp llc nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_hdmi nvidia_uvm(O) nvidia_drm(PO) nvidia_modeset(PO) edac_mce_amd snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg kvm_amd snd_hda_codec snd_usb_audio kvm snd_hda_core snd_usbmidi_lib nvidia(PO) snd_hwdep snd_seq_midi mc joydev crct10dif_pclmul snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_pcm input_leds ghash_clmulni_intel snd_seq drm_kms_helper aesni_intel ipmi_devintf snd_seq_device snd_timer crypto_simd ipmi_msghandler cryptd ucsi_ccg fb_sys_fops glue_helper snd
[mar giu 30 22:36:21 2020]  syscopyarea typec_ucsi sysfillrect wmi_bmof k10temp typec sysimgblt soundcore ccp mac_hid sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev drm lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 btrfs zstd_compress raid10 raid456 async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq async_xor async_tx xor raid6_pq libcrc32c raid0 multipath linear hid_logitech_hidpp raid1 wacom hid_logitech_dj hid_generic uas usbhid usb_storage hid crc32_pclmul i2c_piix4 r8169 i2c_nvidia_gpu ahci realtek libahci wmi gpio_amdpt gpio_generic
[mar giu 30 22:36:21 2020] CPU: 9 PID: 1396 Comm: btrfs-transacti Tainted: P           OE     5.4.0-39-generic #43-Ubuntu
[mar giu 30 22:36:21 2020] Hardware name: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd MS-7B86/B450-A PRO MAX (MS-7B86), BIOS M.73 06/10/2020
[mar giu 30 22:36:21 2020] RIP: 0010:btrfs_run_delayed_refs+0x13c/0x190 [btrfs]
[mar giu 30 22:36:21 2020] Code: 41 5f 5d c3 49 8b 55 50 f0 48 0f ba aa 38 ce 00 00 02 72 1b 83 f8 fb 74 34 89 c6 48 c7 c7 b8 51 3f c0 89 45 d0 e8 6f bf b6 f9 <0f> 0b 8b 45 d0 89 c1 ba 8c 08 00 00 4c 89 ef 89 45 d0 48 c7 c6 60
[mar giu 30 22:36:21 2020] RSP: 0018:ffff9be900cf7d70 EFLAGS: 00010282
[mar giu 30 22:36:21 2020] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000068 RCX: 0000000000000006
[mar giu 30 22:36:21 2020] RDX: 0000000000000007 RSI: 0000000000000092 RDI: ffff89f7cea578c0
[mar giu 30 22:36:21 2020] RBP: ffff9be900cf7db0 R08: 000000000000064c R09: 0000000000000004
[mar giu 30 22:36:21 2020] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: ffff89f7109df358
[mar giu 30 22:36:21 2020] R13: ffff89f7bd1e39c0 R14: ffff89f65436a540 R15: ffff89f7c97a2d48
[mar giu 30 22:36:21 2020] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff89f7cea40000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[mar giu 30 22:36:21 2020] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[mar giu 30 22:36:21 2020] CR2: 00007f1ce529d000 CR3: 0000000379abc000 CR4: 0000000000340ee0
[mar giu 30 22:36:21 2020] Call Trace:
[mar giu 30 22:36:21 2020]  btrfs_start_dirty_block_groups+0x294/0x460 [btrfs]
[mar giu 30 22:36:21 2020]  btrfs_commit_transaction+0xc3/0x960 [btrfs]
[mar giu 30 22:36:21 2020]  ? start_transaction+0xb5/0x4a0 [btrfs]
[mar giu 30 22:36:21 2020]  transaction_kthread+0x146/0x190 [btrfs]
[mar giu 30 22:36:21 2020]  kthread+0x104/0x140
[mar giu 30 22:36:21 2020]  ? btrfs_cleanup_transaction+0x530/0x530 [btrfs]
[mar giu 30 22:36:21 2020]  ? kthread_park+0x90/0x90
[mar giu 30 22:36:21 2020]  ret_from_fork+0x22/0x40
[mar giu 30 22:36:21 2020] ---[ end trace cb44f0a1d84b02f3 ]---
[mar giu 30 22:36:21 2020] BTRFS: error (device sdc3) in btrfs_run_delayed_refs:2188: errno=-17 Object already exists
[mar giu 30 22:36:21 2020] BTRFS info (device sdc3): forced readonly
```

Thanks for every help

I continue to have this problem. When I make intensive use of the filesystem the problem is immediate. For example when I run an rsync on the filesystem

Comment: Keep checking for BIOS firmware updates, your 6/10 date might have been superceded by a 6/12 version, still marked beta.

Comment: Have you tried without using btrfs, with normal ext4?

Comment: Thanks, I just installed the new bios. Let's see if the problem has been solved

Comment: I have a rather complex scheme of partitions; for example the home is on raid 1 with ext4 filesystem and I have not problems with it

Answer (score 0):

just add this to your boot parameters:

```
pci=assign-busses apicmaintimer idle=poll reboot=cold,hard
```

**1. If using grub, open Terminal:**

sudo nano /etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=assign-busses apicmaintimer idle=poll reboot=cold,hard"

sudo update-grub
```

**2. If using kernelstub (on POP! OS), open Terminal:**

```
sudo kernelstub -a "pci=assign-busses apicmaintimer idle=poll reboot=cold,hard"
```

Restart and enjoy no crash whatsoever! This solution I copied from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1241636/908770) the credits go the orginal poster of that solution

Comment: Thank you for answering. I'm trying the solution. I thought it was an incompatibility because I also encountered other types of crashes. I keep an eye on it.

Comment: Unfortunately in my case this didn't work.
I keep having occasional btrfs crashes.
I have also updated the bios to the latest version, but the problem is still there.