# Ubuntu server 20.04 Ryzen 7 3700X freezes

Tags: server, kernel, 20.04, 64-bit, amd-ryzen

I have a newly assembled desktop that I use as a server it has the following hardware

- Gigabyte x570 Aorus pro
- Ryzen 7 3700x
- Corsair DDR4 Vengeance LPX 2x8GB 3200 C16 Geheugen
- 1TB intel SSD

I'm on the latest 20b bios of Gigabyte and have the stable latest kernel. The server as of late freezes, sometimes it takes 2 days, sometimes a couple of hours. I have read many different forum posts in which people play with memory timings, other settings, which haven't worked for me. So far it's not solved for me yet.

I'm just wondering where I can find the real issue whether it's a hardware problem or the ubuntu kernel not fully cooperating with the x570 chipset or the cpu.

Just now I have implemented this [**answer**](https://askubuntu.com/a/1241636/908770) and seems to be working for now, but I'm still monitoring it. For me the linked solution has worked. I also have an Aorus Elite board, where it's not required. But it works, so I'm not questioning it so far.

Added this line to `/etc/default/grub`

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="pci=assign-busses apicmaintimer idle=poll reboot=cold,hard"`

Hope that helps someone, see the [original post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1241636/908770) for more options

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `sudo lshw -C memory`. Is CPU or RAM overclocked?

Comment: No, nothing is overclocked and XMP is also not enabled, all running on standard bios settings.

Comment: Disabling the Automatic C-State Management in BIOS is what fixed that issue for me, so there's a good chance you're good now.

Comment: Yes, it is working for me right now pretty good, already 12 hours stable. I have just added `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=assign-busses apicmaintimer idle=poll reboot=cold,hard"` to grub

Answer (score 0):

At my config (x570 AORUS ELITE, Ryzen 7500x) I've completely got rid of sporadic freezes by upgrading kernel to x86_64-linux-5.6.0-050600-generic which believed to treat Zen2 right.

Comment: Funny thing is I have the X570 Pro and Elite. The Elite didn't require any changes, 20.04 out of the box with 5.4 works great. It's just the pro

Comment: Is it still the case with kernel 5.6 and does the firmware matter? Today after a long time the computer went to freeze again

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I replaced the processor with a new Ryzen 7 5800x and the freezes have stopped, not more segfaults. I'm also on the latest firmware atm which F33A.

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="pci=assign-busses apicmaintimer idle=poll reboot=cold,hard"`

The above that I posted in the initial post is not a sustainable solution, or changing kernels.