# AMD Ryzen 7 3700X in X570 chipset system hangs

Tags: kernel, 20.04, amd-ryzen

I was trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 of my AMD Ryzen 7 3700X my new mobo (chipset X570, Asrock Steel Legend in particular).

The system freezes (become unresponsive with no feedback nor visible error) after a while.

I tried certain configuration options on the BIOS without success, and have been unable to progress the installation or isolate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Even though that solution is given for a different processor, I was able to solve my problem by following [this other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1241636/165858).

The boot parameters that make everything work (**both** for the installation procedure and for the installed system) are:

```
pci=assign-busses apicmaintimer idle=poll reboot=cold,hard
```

Comment: This fix did not work for me.  I am having similar systems (same mobo but 3900x).  I have also tried disabling C6 with amd-disable-c6.