# Ubuntu 20.04 crashes to black screen when "idle"

Tags: 20.04

This problem started 3 weeks ago. When I login and do not immediately start a YouTube video or a call, I get a black screen with no input working anymore and also not even the power button letting me turn off my machine. Every time this happens I have to turn of my power supply.

So my workaround has been to play a mute video the entire time. I also made sure to uninstall all Gnome Extensions and swapped out the video card and use the Nouveau drivers. Nothing has worked so far.

Thank you so much for help.

Edit: Find solution here https://askubuntu.com/a/1241636/1146650

Comment: Check output of the command `dmesg` maybe there You can find some clues of what is happening.

Comment: I did dmesg five times. The output right before crashing was similar every time.


1. `[30708.764878] audit: type=1400 audit(1604617204.497:1177): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed" pid=83313 comm="cups-browsed" capability=23  capname="sys_nice"`

Comment: 2. `[   30.355723] audit: type=1400 audit(1604645308.052:112): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/8x8/emblems/" pid=3093 comm="pool-org.gnome." requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0`

The others are very similar. Seems like it has something to do with my icon themes.