# How to un-rename drive mount points?

Tags: mount, drive

My computer crashes often (AMD Ryzen is [not a reliable CPU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234299/amd-ryzen-5-3600-ubuntu-20-04-problems)) and after the latest crash, all of my mount points have become duplicated:

```
/media/vadi 
❯ ls -l
total 40
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 May 23 12:25  SSDer
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 May 23 12:32  SSDer1
drwxrwxrwx 1 vadi vadi  120 May 23 11:53  SSDer2
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 May  2 15:06 'USB DISK'
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 May  2 19:30 'USB DISK1'
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 May  7 16:41 'You Ess Bee'
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 May  7 20:03 'You Ess Bee1'
```

`findmnt`:

```
 findmnt
TARGET                                      SOURCE             FSTYPE         OPTIONS
/                                           /dev/sda6          ext4           rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro
├─/sys                                      sysfs              sysfs          rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
│ ├─/sys/kernel/security                    securityfs         securityfs     rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
│ ├─/sys/fs/cgroup                          tmpfs              tmpfs          ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755
│ │ ├─/sys/fs/cgroup/unified                cgroup2            cgroup2        rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate
│ │ ├─/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd                cgroup             cgroup         rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,name=systemd
│ │ ├─/sys/fs/cgroup/memory                 cgroup             cgroup         rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory
│ │ ├─/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset                 cgroup             cgroup         rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset
│ │ ├─/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct            cgroup             cgroup         rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct
│ │ ├─/sys/fs/cgroup/blkio                  cgroup             cgroup         rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio
│ │ ├─/sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb                cgroup             cgroup         rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb
│ │ ├─/sys/fs/cgroup/pids                   cgroup             cgroup         rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids
│ │ ├─/sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio       cgroup             cgroup         rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio
│ │ ├─/sys/fs/cgroup/devices                cgroup             cgroup         rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices
│ │ ├─/sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event             cgroup             cgroup         rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event
│ │ ├─/sys/fs/cgroup/rdma                   cgroup             cgroup         rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,rdma
│ │ └─/sys/fs/cgroup/freezer                cgroup             cgroup         rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer
│ ├─/sys/fs/pstore                          pstore             pstore         rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
│ ├─/sys/firmware/efi/efivars               efivarfs           efivarfs       rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
│ ├─/sys/fs/bpf                             none               bpf            rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700
│ ├─/sys/kernel/debug                       debugfs            debugfs        rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
│ ├─/sys/kernel/tracing                     tracefs            tracefs        rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
│ ├─/sys/fs/fuse/connections                fusectl            fusectl        rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
│ └─/sys/kernel/config                      configfs           configfs       rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
├─/proc                                     proc               proc           rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
│ └─/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc                systemd-1          autofs         rw,relatime,fd=28,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=199
│   └─/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc              binfmt_misc        binfmt_misc    rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
├─/dev                                      udev               devtmpfs       rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=16382760k,nr_inodes=4095690,mode=755
│ ├─/dev/pts                                devpts             devpts         rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000
│ ├─/dev/shm                                tmpfs              tmpfs          rw,nosuid,nodev
│ ├─/dev/mqueue                             mqueue             mqueue         rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
│ └─/dev/hugepages                          hugetlbfs          hugetlbfs      rw,relatime,pagesize=2M
├─/run                                      tmpfs              tmpfs          rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=3289056k,mode=755
│ ├─/run/lock                               tmpfs              tmpfs          rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k
│ ├─/run/user/125                           tmpfs              tmpfs          rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=3289052k,mode=700,uid=125,gid=130
│ │ └─/run/user/125/gvfs                    gvfsd-fuse         fuse.gvfsd-fus rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=125,group_id=130
│ ├─/run/snapd/ns                           tmpfs[/snapd/ns]   tmpfs          rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=3289056k,mode=755
│ │ ├─/run/snapd/ns/canonical-livepatch.mnt nsfs[mnt:[4026533036]]
│ │ │                                                          nsfs           rw
│ │ └─/run/snapd/ns/snap-store.mnt          nsfs[mnt:[4026533111]]
│ │                                                            nsfs           rw
│ ├─/run/user/1000                          tmpfs              tmpfs          rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=3289052k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000
│ │ ├─/run/user/1000/gvfs                   gvfsd-fuse         fuse.gvfsd-fus rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000
│ │ ├─/run/user/1000/doc                    /dev/fuse          fuse           rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000
│ │ └─/run/user/1000/keybase/kbfs           /dev/fuse          fuse           rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000
│ ├─/run/docker/netns/e5be4d3d95a3          nsfs[net:[4026532690]]
│ │                                                            nsfs           rw
│ └─/run/docker/netns/b6f00f94b562          nsfs[net:[4026532715]]
│                                                              nsfs           rw
├─/snap/clion/149                           /dev/loop2         squashfs       ro,nodev,relatime
├─/snap/pdf2go/45                           /dev/loop11        squashfs       ro,nodev,relatime
├─/snap/chromium/1568                       /dev/loop13        squashfs       ro,nodev,relatime
├─/snap/pyqt5-runtime/4                     /dev/loop14        squashfs       ro,nodev,relatime
├─/snap/qalculate/356                       /dev/loop12        squashfs       ro,nodev,relatime
├─/snap/snapd/11588                         /dev/loop15        squashfs       ro,nodev,relatime
├─/snap/gtk-common-themes/1515              /dev/loop16        squashfs       ro,nodev,relatime
├─/snap/node/4150                           /dev/loop17        squashfs       ro,nodev,relatime
├─/snap/powershell/160                      /dev/loop18        squashfs       ro,nodev,relatime
├─/snap/kruler/66                           /dev/loop19        squashfs       ro,nodev,relatime
├─/snap/chromium/1589                       /dev/loop20        squashfs       ro,nodev,relatime
├─/snap/core20/1026                         /dev/loop21        squashfs       ro,nodev,relatime
├─/snap/node/4594                           /dev/loop22        squashfs       ro,nodev,relatime
├─/snap/pdf2go/43                           /dev/loop23        squashfs       ro,nodev,relatime
├─/snap/kruler/64                           /dev/loop24        squashfs       ro,nodev,relatime
├─/snap/core20/975                          /dev/loop25        squashfs       ro,nodev,relatime
├─/snap/core/11081                          /dev/loop26        squashfs       ro,nodev,relatime
├─/snap/clion/151                           /dev/loop27        squashfs       ro,nodev,relatime
├─/snap/snap-store/518                      /dev/loop28        squashfs       ro,nodev,relatime
├─/snap/qalculate/360                       /dev/loop29        squashfs       ro,nodev,relatime
├─/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/60                  /dev/loop30        squashfs       ro,nodev,relatime
├─/snap/glimpse-editor/194                  /dev/loop31        squashfs       ro,nodev,relatime
├─/snap/kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-15-core20/14  /dev/loop32        squashfs       ro,nodev,relatime
├─/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145                 /dev/loop33        squashfs       ro,nodev,relatime
├─/snap/snapd/11841                         /dev/loop34        squashfs       ro,nodev,relatime
├─/snap/core18/2066                         /dev/loop35        squashfs       ro,nodev,relatime
├─/snap/snap-store/467                      /dev/loop36        squashfs       ro,nodev,relatime
├─/snap/rider/201                           /dev/loop37        squashfs       ro,nodev,relatime
├─/boot/efi                                 /dev/sda1          vfat           rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mi
├─/snap/core18/1997                         /dev/loop8         squashfs       ro,nodev,relatime
├─/snap/code/65                             /dev/loop10        squashfs       ro,nodev,relatime
├─/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66                  /dev/loop9         squashfs       ro,nodev,relatime
├─/snap/gtk-common-themes/1514              /dev/loop4         squashfs       ro,nodev,relatime
├─/snap/code/64                             /dev/loop3         squashfs       ro,nodev,relatime
├─/snap/gtk2-common-themes/13               /dev/loop5         squashfs       ro,nodev,relatime
├─/snap/core/10958                          /dev/loop6         squashfs       ro,nodev,relatime
├─/snap/canonical-livepatch/98              /dev/loop1         squashfs       ro,nodev,relatime
├─/snap/canonical-livepatch/99              /dev/loop0         squashfs       ro,nodev,relatime
├─/snap/glimpse-editor/191                  /dev/loop7         squashfs       ro,nodev,relatime
├─/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9af4dffdf892f35a7f8c121edcf09b65ab6a6650cf0724f6f2bdf10758fb88e8/merged
│                                           overlay            overlay        rw,relatime,lowerdir=/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/W7LTH424DCU2JWDDBESKH4LYWV:/var
├─/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6aa511b5efbb0343d21871d85ffa65b63268492cc15a724410165030398f4b68/merged
│                                           overlay            overlay        rw,relatime,lowerdir=/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/QBDCKYLOETB2GBGMVYMMPQ7KAD:/var
└─/keybase                                  keybase-redirector fuse           ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other

/media/vadi 
❯
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: for automount with udidks2! Umount evrything under /media/vadi and make sure there is nothing in this folders; then erase them. when you plugin an usb-stick or something else the folder (for mountpoint) will be recreated by udisks2

Comment: I can't unmount SSDer: it gives an incomprehensible error message - https://imgur.com/a/RNpNIMO

Comment: Please add `findmnt` to you question.

Comment: Yep, added findmnt.

Comment: There is nothing mounted under `/media/vadi/` make sure the folders are empty and erase them.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Want to submit it as an answer?